# How do you create a div with a triangle shape using css only?

Tags: html, css

I want a div that has an "angle like shape on the left". How can I create this with CSS3 only? I am assuming this requires 2 divs? I know I can make a rectangle div and fill it back, and have yellow text. Though I don't know what I can do to make the triange shape on the left. Can it be done with done div only? Or does it need 2? Looking for the best way to do this.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using `linear-gradient`. Demo:

```css
.text {
  width: 400px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50px, black 50px);
  padding-left: 100px;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>Some Name Here</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not try something like this:

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid black;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  float: left;
}

.text {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
<div class="text"><h1>Some Name Here</h1></div>
```

See [How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work) for more info on this.

Comment: Additionally, you can use `::before` to do this so you don't need two elements.

Comment: @jhpratt I couldn't figure out how but I agree, that would be the more economical approach

Answer (score 1):

You can use of Pseudo Elements `::before` or `::after`

```css
.triangle {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
  color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.triangle::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 19px solid #000;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: -38px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
  text-here
</div>
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/80p6hL11/1/)

Style Accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`clip-path`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/) but it has [not so good browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path). I'm using `100vmax 100vmax` here to achieve 45 degrees clipping. Demo:

```css
.text {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100vmax 100vmax, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(100vmax 100vmax, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  padding-left: 100px;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>Some Name Here</h1>
</div>
```